# Angular 2 Material 2 datepicker date format validation

Tags: angular, angular-material

same question like [Angular 2 Material 2 datepicker date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452966/angular-2-material-2-datepicker-date-format)

when I change date format let's say to de (dd.mm.YYYY) standart, it works if I choose date from datepicker, but if I fill in manually it't considered as invalid date (still expecting old format mm.dd.YYYY)

So for me it looks like representation format was changed right, but logic behind datepicker validation should be changed with some additional changes

Comment: created issue on github, u can track progress here https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7143