# angular material 2, change datepicker Date Format "MM/DD/YYYY" to "DD/MM/YYYY" strange behavior

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I just tried to change the angular material 2 date-picker default Date Format **MM/DD/YYYY** to **DD/MM/YYYY** or **DD.MM.YYYY** or at least **DD-MM-YYYY**

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452966/angular-2-material-2-datepicker-date-format) and as mentioned in [the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452966/angular-2-material-2-datepicker-date-format)

> `providers: [{provide: MD_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_NATIVE_DATE_FORMATS}]`

So tried following approaches

Approach [1 plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/P0pcQYlT5gUHxnbBr5wM?p=preview) : to get in **DD-MM-YYYY** format

Approach [2 plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/HnWQUFTkfUjhK8GbC6FR?p=preview) : to get in **DD.MM.YYYY** format

Approach [3 plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ftwG63cK3AtXdcigjrGM?p=preview) : to get in **DD/MM/YYYY** format

but each of above approach working ordinary until I select a **Date** 1 to 12,

for ex: Today date is **25th September 2017**, if I select **12th September 2017** as date, then once click datepicker button again I can see calender date, taken as 09th of November 2017(09/11/2017) not as (11/09/2017) , which is seems default date format not override correctly

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**1/ DOCS: [By cusomising the parse and display format with a custom date atapter](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker.md#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats)**

In the custom Date Adapter (yours is AppDateAdapter), add a parse method to parse the new date format (DD/MM/YYY) to a date valid date:

for example for the  **DD/MM/YYYY**  format, parse could be:

```
   parse(value: any): Date | null {
    if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('/') > -1)) {
      const str = value.split('/');
      const year = Number(str[2]);
      const month = Number(str[1]) - 1;
      const date = Number(str[0]);
      return new Date(year, month, date);
    }
    const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
    return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
  }
```

working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-format?embed=1&file=app/date.adapter.ts

your complete date adapter:

```
export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
    parse(value: any): Date | null {
        if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('/') > -1)) {
          const str = value.split('/');
          const year = Number(str[2]);
          const month = Number(str[1]) - 1;
          const date = Number(str[0]);
          return new Date(year, month, date);
        }
        const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
        return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
      }
   format(date: Date, displayFormat: any): string {
       if (displayFormat == "input") {
           let day = date.getDate();
           let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
           let year = date.getFullYear();
           return this._to2digit(day) + '/' + this._to2digit(month) + '/' + year;
       } else {
           return date.toDateString();
       }
   }

   private _to2digit(n: number) {
       return ('00' + n).slice(-2);
   } 
}
```

The advantage of this approach is you could also custom the format of `monthYearLabel` in the display constants and could have a calendar which looks like:

[image]

Comment: thanks but changing this to 2017/06/28 does end up to weird situation.

Comment: @Fetra R. okay, let's put it this way: i only changed this line
 return this._to2digit(day) + '/' + this._to2digit(month) + '/' + year; to year + '/'+ this._to2digit(day) + '/' + this._to2digit(month); Isn't it enough?

Comment: This one that you just added is actually working! Thank you!

Comment: This brokes if the input is numeric...would it be bad to add a "displayFormat" to save the selected format in the format method?

Comment: And why "displayFormat" is expected to be an Object if actually it's a string?

Comment: I created a simple and easily customisable `DateAdapter` using Day.js and created a Gist of it: https://gist.github.com/wottpal/4211f4c01c41b16be181110273cff5a9

Comment: @Fetrarij really nice solution. But there seems to have some problem. Try typing a invalid date directly in the input filed. For example 88/88/8888 and it is getting converted into a random date as soon as the focus goes out of the field.
Apart from that is it normal that the each time i open a datepicker the format function is getting called 30/31(number of days in the monts) times?

Answer (score 92):

Use this in your `app.module.ts` under the `providers:` array.

`{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'}`

Comment: this is what he tried at the beginning, and it acts wierd still

Comment: Thanks man! I had the same problem and I used just 'nl' before. With 'nl-NL' it works properly.

Comment: yep this does work, but you need to import to your app.module as well
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material';

Comment: Great.. probably the easiest way...thanks for sharing

Comment: It will help to change display value not actual Date value. I am getting Date value like this format "Fri Oct 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)"

Comment: @NewazSharifAmit This solution is for showing the locale date in the material DatePicker.If you want to convert its value you need to do `.toLocaleDateString()` after it.

Comment: I have the same problem as explained.
How can I set this if my app is standalone and doesn't have `app.module.ts`.

Comment: @JosipMaričević I think you can add providers now in Main.ts. refer to this doc https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#environment-injectors

Answer (score 13):

One of possible solution is simply defining your own input format:

```
export const DD_MM_YYYY_Format = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'LL',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
};

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    providers: [
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: DD_MM_YYYY_Format},
    ]
})
export class AppComponent implemets OnInit {
   // ... some code
}
```

The following code tells the injector to return a `DD_MM_YYYY_Format` when something asks for the `MAT_DATE_FORMATS` (read [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#the-provide-object-literal) for more details). Inside your custom format, property `display.dateInput` is set to `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Answer (score 8):

Use it on your app.module.ts file under provider's section as below

```
 providers: [
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB'}
  ],
```

Answer (score 4):

Updated version of Fetrarij, for date format dd.mm.yyyy with first day monday:

- in app.module.ts:

```
 
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'sk-SK' },
```

- date adapter extension:

```
 

    @Injectable()
    export class DateAdapterSK extends NativeDateAdapter {

        getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
            return 1;
        }

        parse(value: any): Date | null {
            if ((typeof value === 'string') && (value.indexOf('.') > -1)) {
                const str = value.split('.');
                const year = Number(str[2]);
                const month = Number(str[1]) - 1;
                const date = Number(str[0]);
                return new Date(year, month, date);
            }
            const timestamp = typeof value === 'number' ? value : Date.parse(value);
            return isNaN(timestamp) ? null : new Date(timestamp);
        }

    }
```

Work for me. Angular 6.

Comment: i a solved including part in only code app.module.ts {provider}

Comment: love this solution, just what i was looking for! luckily i just care about the display, and 'en-GB' works too!