# Angular Material date picker isn't rendering correctly

Tags: angular-material

I am trying to incorporate Angular material date picker. I am following the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jdypxbxgoyb?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.ts) but it is not rendering correctly. Here is what I see.

[image]

I am really confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/q/46392275/9775003)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, different issue.

Comment: @AhmadQardahji Could it be have to do with something in your CSS?

Comment: Could be, I used an npm package date range picker and it renders just fine now.