# Dynamically set the format of the date-picker based on user format preference

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have a scenario where the date format will be provided from the backend. So I want to dynamically set the date format based on the value provided.

> ex: 'DD/MM/YYYY', 'MM/DD/YYYY' or 'YYYY/MM/DD'

I have gone through the Angular Material for [Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings) but wasn't able to find a way to implement.

Please find the minimal code over [here (Stack Blitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8netsa?embed=1&file=app/date.adapter.ts).

Note: The compiler is throwing error since I am not able to fetch the date format from my dummy service `datepicker-moment.service.ts`

Comment: You can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392275/angular-material-2-change-datepicker-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-s

Comment: please refer this may helpful http://blog.manishsood.in/change-date-format-in-material-datepicker-angular-2-and-angular-4/?i=1