# Angular material date picker input is forcing wrong date format

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, format

I have a problem with setting the date format on the Material Date picker input, but he is always showing the wrong format. I have set it up exactly as it is in [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples#datepicker-formats).
Here is what I have in providers:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS],
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
  ],
```

where MY-FORMATS is:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
}
```

The main problem here is that the `dateInput` format is not working, I can confirm that `monthYearLabel` for example, and the other two are working and responding to editing `MY_FORMATS` and are correctly displayed in the popup when selecting a date, but the date in input is always forcing `mm/dd/yyyy` format, and the only time that formatting is working, is when I set `dateInput` format to look like this, for any other it just shows `mm/dd/yyyy` in the input without any errors.

I have also tried creating a custom date adapter class and using it instead of MomentDateAdapter, but the same thing is happening, all labels in the date picker popup are correctly formated, except the date in the input field.

Whichever format approach that is added through providers I have tried, is behaving the same. Would be good if I could attach somehow to input value changes, and format it manually on every change, if not able to solve it this way. So any recommendation is very welcome

I don't know if is it possible that there is somewhere globally locale set that is interfering with this or something like that.

There is this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392275/angular-material-2-change-datepicker-date-format-mm-dd-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-s?rq=2) with the same behavior, for me same thing is happening as he explained, if I use set `dd/mm/yyyy` format, it displays correctly, but only while `dd` is 12 or less, if day number is higher, it just shows `mm/dd/yyyy` format in input and nothing else.
But i can't

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'yourVal' },
```

in your app.module.ts file
Where useValue corresponding to your locale e.g 'en-US'

Comment: I tried adding it to app.confing, since my app is standalone, didn't help.