# How to manually set date format in matDatepicker (angular 4)

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design

```
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput name=""       
     [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker"  
      [max]="maxDate"                                                                                                        
        placeholder="Select Date Of Birth"                                                                   
         id="dateOfBirth"                                                                   
          [value]="value"                                                                    
           onkeydown="return false" />                                                             
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker mat-open-on-focus></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is my snippet which is implemented for two-way binding.

```
Value return JS date object output as follow 

Current output:
"Mon Jan 01 1900 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Required Output:
01/01/1990 (MM/DD/YYYY).
```

I have refer following links, but did not get expected output - 
    [Angular 2 Material 2 datepicker date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452966/angular-2-material-2-datepicker-date-format)

Comment: I use momentjs for this https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Yes, 1) we can use moment to get output as "date string". 2) 2nd way to get date string "toLocaleDateString()". But as of now i am using Angular material (matDatePicker) which required Date Object to bind value, If we provide string to bind, It shows an error:-                                                                Error: Datepicker: Value must be either a date object recognized by the DateAdapter or an ISO 8601 string. Instead got: 12/31/1899

Comment: Well how does your date look like when you receive it?

Comment: It's a string "mm/dd/yyyy"

Comment: Well if it looks like that your datepicker should work just fine and display the correct format that you wish. Please make demo to showcase your issue :)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.
We have use material way to display the required formatted date.