# Angular material datepicker custom format

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created a custom directive to add features to the existing matDatePicker control. This directive has an Input attribute called format which gives date format at run time. I have provided the MyDateAdapter as mention in 
[Angular 2 Material 2 datepicker date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452966/angular-2-material-2-datepicker-date-format)

My question is; how I can set the Input format value to the datepicker date format at run time as an when my value of format get changed.

**My Directive:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dateFormat]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: DateFormatDirective,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MyDateAdapter
    },
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS
    }
  ]
})
export class DateFormatDirective {
  @Input('dateFormat') format: string;
}
```

MyDateAdapter class and  MY_DATE_FORMATS constant  [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44452966/angular-2-material-2-datepicker-date-format)

Answer (score 3):

After looking into material datepicker and NativeDateAdapter source code I found the solution for above issue.

**modify MyDateAdapter**

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
export class MyDateAdapter  extends NativeDateAdapter {
    format:string;
    constructor( private datepipe: DatePipe,  platform: Platform,translate: TranslateService) {
        super('en', platform);
        translate.get('dateFormat').subscribe(ts =>{ 
             this.format=dateFormat;
        });
    }
    format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
        if (displayFormat === 'input') {
            return this.datepipe.transform(date, this.format);
        } else {
            return date.toDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Add factory function:**

```
export function createDateAdapterLoader (dp: DatePipe,  platform: Platform,ts: TranslateService) {
  return new MyDateAdapter(dp,  platform, ts);
}
```

**modify Directive:**

```
    import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
    import {Platform} from '@angular/cdk/platform';
    @Directive({
      selector: '[dateFormat]',
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
          useExisting: DateFormatDirective,
          multi: true
        },
        {
          provide: DateAdapter,
          useFactory: createDateAdapterLoader,
          deps: [DatePipe, Platform ,TranslateService]
        },
        {
          provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_DATE_FORMATS
        }
      ]
    })
    export class DateFormatDirective {
      @Input('dateFormat') format: string;
    }
```

You need to provide DatePipe in AppModule.

This is called Factory provider to create the dependent value dynamically!! [refer](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#factory-providers)

To get format value from i18n file you can use any internationalization (i18n) library, eg:[@ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)